# ASP.NET Core Authentication middleware bypassing expired access tokens associated with cookie

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, cookies, jwt, identityserver4

I have an ASPNETcore MVC client authenticating with IdentityServer4 in order to access an API.

The API expects the bearer token in a request header, when the bearer token expires, the request is short-circuited and a 401 Unauthorized is returned.

The MVC client after successful authentication, received the cookie from IdentityServer4 and associates that with a cookie.

**The problem I'm encountering is that when the user's access token(JWT) expires, the MVC authentication middleware is considering the request as authenticated, as the cookie is still present... so when a request is sent to my API, it's failing there**
I expect the MVC client auth middleware to be responsible for requesting new tokens.

**This is my MVC auth configuration:**
[image]

**This is my IdentityServer client definition:**

[image]

Comment: You need to add Refresh Token in order to bring a new JWT token.